# Updating from an old enumitem package - Lubuntu

Tags: packages, enumitem, linux, package-options

I've installed Texmaker on my netbook running LXLE (built on Lubuntu 12.04) and when I tried to compile a file I'd been working on with Texmaker on Windows, I get an error saying:

> Unknown option `inline' for package`enumitem'.

I assume this means that it had installed an old version of enumitem. How would I go about updating enumitem?

I downloaded it from CTAN and placed the .sty into ~/texmf and into /usr/local/share/texmf and into the directory containing my .tex file, I've tried running texhash. I don't really know what those should have done, but whatever it is none of them worked!

Instead of working out how to do this, I in fact just downloaded TexLive 2015 from www.tug.org and the installation solved my problem, but I'd like to know in the future!

Comment: The current version of TeX Live is 2015. Are you sure you installed a 2012 version?

Comment: I did indeed mean 2015... Sometimes it's nice to think it's still 2012 and Team GB just came 3rd in the Olympics.

Comment: @christuart: I've used ubuntu only once and was not happy with the packaging of `TeX` there, so I tried the usual `install-tl` vanilla installation and it worked out of the box, basically on any Linux system I run

Answer (score 1):

One quick and easy way would be to place the .sty file in the folder containing the .tex file. This can be useful if you don't have access to the /textmf folder, say if you're working on a network machine.

Comment: That's one thing I tried, but it didn't seem to work. Perhaps it was being overridden by the old version somewhere else?

Comment: I had a similar problem a couple of weeks ago (I got the error `LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'shortlabels' for package 'enumitem'.`) and putting the latest version of the .sty file in the folder containing the .tex file worked just fine, hence why I suggested it. (Apologies btw for missing in your original post that you'd already tried that.) It's just an idea, but how about removing the .sty file from /texmf and /usr/local/share/texmf and placing it just in the directory with the .tex file? I wonder if there's some sort of clash between the .sty files in the different locations.